# Why can't I seem to levitate using the /effect command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I type the following command I get the particles and icon but I do not levitate.

```
effect @p levitation 10 1 false
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. The command you provided works correctly for me.

Comment: Are you playing on a server that has some flawed anti-cheat? Or are you playing on a world? Besides for that I can’t think of a reason for this bizarre issue besides maybe a weird bug in whatever version you’re using.

Comment: I am playing on a local world on my computer.  Interesting thing is that I told it to levitate for a longer period of time and after a few minutes it did start levitating.  Still weird that it does not start levitating until a few minutes after the command. The particles and icon show up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Your old command should work. Maybe check your setup?

```
/effect @s levitation 1000 1
```

Comment: This didn’t really provide an answer.

Comment: Please don't add an answer until you're sure of the problem at hand. Right now, it's unclear what the problem is, because the command is correct on its own. Don't jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you’re not flying while trying to use the levitation effect. If you are, you *will* get the particles and icon, and the effect will show up when you press <kbd>Z</kbd>, but the effect will *not* make you levitate. You can rule out the possibility of flying by entering survival mode with `/gamemode s`.

Comment: This is useful in case any levitation commands or command blocks you may have in your world go out of control and you want to be immune to the effect.

Answer (score 0):

The effect ends after 0.5 seconds with the given command. By the time you'd like to test it, it's over.